# E4 application Generate part from xsd with xml binding

Tags: data-binding, rcp, e4

I can generate beans from an .xsd file using JAXB. What I would like to do is generate a part in an eclipse 4 application from a .xsd file.

This can all be done manually using JFace binding with a simple example of a name property. I need to do this for hundreds of fields, hence the generator requirement.

I have been searching for examples on how to do this even with non e4 applications.

Or is this a crazy idea?

[JFace binding tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataBinding/article.html)

Comment: Of course all layouts would need to be manually changed.

Comment: I am looking at castor explained quite well here http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075952/java-xml/use-xml-data-binding-to-do-your-laundry.html